# Get N largest values from pandas array, with index and column headings intact

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say I have just calculated a correlation matrix. Using a pandas dataframe, I would now like to obtain the highest correlations with their axes names in place.

E.g. from:

```
   a, b, c, d, e, f 
a, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
b, 1, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6,
c, 2, 3, 0, 5, 6, 7,
d, 3, 4, 5, 0, 7, 8,
e, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 9,
f, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0
```

get:

```
e f 9
f d 8
f c 7
e d 7
```

etc...

I have read through the pandas docs and see the groupby methods as well as functions like head, but I'm a bit lost on how one would be expected to perform this operation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `stack` here, which will produce a Series with the row and column information in the index, and then call `nlargest` on that:

```
>>> df.stack()
a  a    0
   b    1
   c    2
   d    3
   e    4
   f    5
b  a    1
   b    0
   c    3
[etc.]
>>> df.stack().nlargest(6)
e  f    9
f  e    9
d  f    8
f  d    8
c  f    7
d  e    7
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. I am getting a strange error. AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'nlargest'

Comment: @Sirrah: `nlargest` (docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nlargest.html)) was introduced relatively recently.  You're probably working with an older version of `pandas`.  You can always sort and then subselect, e.g. `s = df.stack()` and then `s.sort(ascending=False); s.iloc[:6]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.argpartition`. Dropping down to NumPy here seems to give a 2-3x performance improvement.

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.abs(np.random.randn(500, 400)))

def jpp(df, n):
    flat_indices = np.argpartition(df.values.ravel(), -n)[-n:]
    row_idx, col_idx = np.unravel_index(flat_indices, df.values.shape)
    indices = list(zip(row_idx, col_idx))
    values = df.values[(row_idx, col_idx)]
    res_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(indices)
    return pd.Series(values, index=res_idx).sort_values(ascending=False)

def dsm(df, n):
    return df.stack().nlargest(n)

assert jpp(df, n=1000).equals(dsm(df, n=1000))

%timeit jpp(df, n=1000)  # 4.65 ms per loop
%timeit dsm(df, n=1000)  # 12.1 ms per loop

%timeit jpp(df, n=5)     # 3.33 ms per loop
%timeit dsm(df, n=5)     # 10.1 ms per loop
```